# Readline throws error at last line: has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I have a >200 line CSV file, and Node's readline module throws this error at the end of the document:

```
  has no method 'on'
    at new Interface (readline.js:107:11)
    at Object.exports.createInterface (readline.js:41:10)
```

The document does have a blank line at the end of it, could that be causing the problem?

```
request('http://csvdata.com/csvfile', function (error, response, csvData) {
            // If Request Successful
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                // Defaults
                var instream  = csvData;
                var outstream = new stream;
                var rl        = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);
                // Go through each line
                rl.on('line', function(line) {
                    console.log(line);
                });
```

Comment: `readline.createInterface()` expects an object for the options, not a parameter for each option. Try `readline.createInterface({input: instream, output: outstream});` Edit: just reading old docs, it used to accept multiple parameters, the updated docs only allow one, which is an object of options.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  I think it might be because the .on('line) fires when it reaches a break '/n' in the doc, and perhaps my doc is missing one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem 
what I see is "readline" are 2 different modules, 
1. refers https://www.npmjs.org/package/readline (external module) 
2. refers http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html (core module)

Then "on" method is supported by external module https://www.npmjs.org/package/readline.

See if this helps